# How to show and hide div on scroll

Tags: javascript

I current have a working script, that shows a div when I scroll pass #idX and hides the div when I scroll above #idX. However I also need the div to hide if I scroll pass another element down the page. This is where my code conflicts with each other. Do you guys have any suggestion?

It should go like this

```js
< #idX hide
> #idX show
> #idX2 hide
< #idX2 show
```

This is the my code so far which shows the div when I pass the element of my choice and hides when above it. I cant get it to hide when scrolling pass another element down the page. :/

```js
var offsetTop = $(".elementor-element-27967803").offset().top;
$(window).scroll(function(){
  var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  if(scrollTop > offsetTop){
    $("#nav-menu-shortcut").fadeIn(500);
  }
   if(scrollTop <offsetTop){
    $("#nav-menu-shortcut").fadeOut(500);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

While you need to show the menu according to the offsetTop of two divisions so instead of passed offsetTop of one div make array for both of your div then according to your result situation create the suitable if statment to achieve the result

```
var offsetTop = [$("#IDX").offset().top,$("#IDX2").offset().top];
$(window).scroll(function(){
  var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  if(scrollTop > offsetTop[0]){
    $("#nav-menu-shortcut").fadeIn(500);
  }
  if(scrollTop >offsetTop[1]){
$("#nav-menu-shortcut").fadeOut(500);
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, when I run this it flickers out and in. #idx & #idX2 are just divs on the page, #nav-menu-shortcut is the element that shows and hides whenever you scroll pass them.

Comment: I change the code as I understand from you , if it is not the required code note that all the work is to set if statment which represents your desired result

Comment: Your code looks almost exactly like the OP's code. I see the differences, but you don't explain anything. This answer would be useful if you explained what was wrong with the OP's code, what you changed to fix it, and especially _why_ your changes make it work. As it is, this is just a code-dump and doesn't really _answer_ the question "How to show and hide div on scroll"